# Complex Integral with respect to Arc Length

Tags: complex-analysis

The exercise is to prove that for $0<\rho\neq|\alpha|$,

$$\int_{|z|=\rho}{\frac{|dz|}{|z-\alpha|^2}} = \frac{2\pi\rho}{|\rho^2-|\alpha|^2|}$$

I tried making a substition where $z=\rho e^{it}$, $t$ goes from $0$ to $2\pi$, and this leads to the integral $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\rho}{\rho ^2 + |\alpha|^2 -2\rho Re(\bar{\alpha}e^{it})}dt$. But that's somehow cumbersome to solve, if solvable at all.

Is there a simpler way? It looks like Cauchy's integral formula, but the $|dz|$ doesn't let me use it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the circle $\lvert z\rvert = \rho$, with the parametrisation $z = \rho e^{it}$, we have

$$\lvert dz\rvert = \rho\,dt = \rho\, \frac{dz}{iz}.$$

So you can write the integral as

$$\rho\int_{\lvert z\rvert = \rho} \frac{dz}{iz(z-\alpha)(\overline{z} - \overline{\alpha})}.$$

This can be transformed into a form where the residue theorem is applicable by noting $\lvert z\rvert^2 = \rho^2$ on the circle.